# How can I define a regex format?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a decimal number, `s`, that needs to fulfill the following conditions:

```
((s>=97 && s<=122 )&&(s>=65 && s<=90)&&(s>=48 && s<=57)&&
((s>=33 && s<=47)||(s>=58 && s<=64)||(s>=91 && s<=96)||(s>=123 && s<=126))){
```

The int `s` is actually based on the decimal number of ASCII table.

Can the condition above be converted into regex format?

Comment: your question is unclear for answers ...

Comment: Why a regex? Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: I would like to filter the password entered by user so that the password consists of capital and small letters, numbers and symbols... the above condition is based on ASCII table, but I would like to create a regex pattern that fulfil the requirements...

Comment: There's an error in your condition as well: s can't be between 97 and 122 AND be between 65 and 90.

Comment: I think the edited version of this question is worth keeping open.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. But you shouldn't. The conditions above are numeric operations, and as such will be type-safe, fast, and easy to understand if you keep them as numeric operations.

The conditions you've listed boil down to something like this:

```
if (s >= 33 && s <= 126) {
    switch ((int)s) {    
        case 47:
        case 57:
        case 64:
        case 90:
        case 97:
        case 122:
            return s == (int)s;
        default: 
            return true;    
    }
}
return false;
```

I'm not sure the `s == (int)s` thing will fly, since I'm a C# guy. The idea of that line is to yield true if `s` is an integer, and false otherwise.

Short, sweet alternative:

```
float[] temp = new float[] { 47, 57, 64, 90, 97 };
return s >= 33 && s <= 126 && (!temp.contains((int)s) || s == (int)s);
```

The above is the "right" way to do this. If you must use a regex, you could get by with this:

```
String pattern = "([459]7|64|90|122)\\.[0-9]+";
return s >= 33 && s <= 126 && !s.toString().matches(pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to resolve a large conditional of ranges into a regular expression class
that has no overlap, a utility like this will work. Not sure if you going to embed
the utility code or just the character class outcome.

Unfortunatly, I'm not a Java expert. So this utility is written in Perl. Maybe you
can convert it into Java or just use it to generate a class.

This is an ASCII sample, it just takes a large conditional and tests it against a   continuous range of numbers (0 - 255 in this case), generates a string of characters
based on the character code, then manipulates the string down to a valid character class.

**Edit:** There are two delimiters characters required; $pad and $range, these should be outside the range which could be valid in the *conditional*.

Good Luck!

```
$class = '';
$valid = 0;
$pad   = "\x{100}";
$range = "\x{101}";

for $s (0 .. 255)
{
   if (   ($s >= 33  && $s <= 47)
       || ($s >= 58  && $s <= 64)
       || ($s >= 91  && $s <= 96)
       || ($s >= 123 && $s <= 140)
       || ($s >  4   && $s <  25)
       || ($s >  180)
       || ($s == 0)
  )
   {
      $class .= chr($s);
      $valid = 1;
      # print $s,"\n";
   }
   else {
      $class .= $pad;
   }
}

if ( $valid)
{
   # Escape special class characters
      $class =~ s/([\[\]\-\^\\])/\\$1/g;

   # Compact range, insert delimiter, then remove padding
      $class =~ s/(\\?[^$pad])[^$pad]+(\\?[^$pad])/$1$range$2/g;
      $class =~ s/[$pad]//g;

   # Convert non-printable ASCII characters to hex (does not process delimeter)
      $class =  join '', 
              map { my $v = ord($_);
                    $v != ord($range) && ($v < 32 || ($v > 126 && $v < 256)) ?
                    sprintf("\\x%.2x", $v) : $_
              } split (//, $class);

   # Insert range operator's
      $class =~ s/[$range]/-/g;

   # Print class
      $class = '[' . $class . ']';
      print "\nEquivalent class = ", $class, "\n";
}

else {
    print "\nNothing in range!\n";
}
```

Outputs -

```
Equivalent class = [\x00\x05-\x18!-/:-@\[-`{-\x8c\xb5-\xff]
```